# How do I read static files in a PIG UDF

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to PIG and Hadoop. I have written a PIG UDF which operates on String and returns a string. I actually use a class from an already existing jar which contains the business logic in the udf. The class constructor takes 2 filenames as input which it uses for building some dictionary used for processing the input. How to get it working in mapreduce mode I tried passing the filenames in pig local mode it works fine. But I dont know how to make it work in mapreduce mode? Can distributed cache solve the problem?

Here is my code

```
REGISTER tokenParser.jar

REGISTER sampleudf.jar;


DEFINE TOKENPARSER com.yahoo.sample.ParseToken('conf/input1.txt','conf/input2.xml');

A = LOAD './inputHOP.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (tok:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE TOKENPARSER(tok);
STORE B into 'newTokout' USING PigStorage();
```

From what I understand is tokenParser.jar must be using some sort of BufferedInputReader. Is it possible to make it work without changing tokenParser.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, like in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4959762/73117)  using the [distributed cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959762/if-i-have-a-constructor-that-requires-a-path-to-a-file-how-can-i-fake-that-if/4966099#4966099) is a good way to solve this problem.